# Is it possible to have the auto display sleep less them a minute some how?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, power-management

In the System prefernces Energy Saver section you have "Display Sleep" option.

[image]

The minimum time is a minute. is it possible to tweak that some how to less then a minute?

- Please don't add comments about good / bad idea... just the answer on the technical part.

Comment: To what end? This feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: Not xy problem. play solitaire if you are bored.

Comment: Good luck getting answers with that attitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prints all power saving settings:

```
pmset -g
```

You will see that units are all in minutes (while '0' means 'never'):

```
man pmset
```

In other words, it is not possible.

Comment: Thanks! it seems to be the right answer i'm afraid :)